# MySQL update and append multiple rows of data with concat

Tags: mysql

Here's a sample of the data I'm pulling from:

```
+-----+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| id  |    name    | carrier | tracking |    date    |
+-----+------------+---------+----------+------------+
| 123 | john smith |   UPS   | abcdefgh | 2018-06-22 |
| 123 | john smith |   USPS  | 12345678 | 2018-06-23 |
+-----+------------+---------+----------+------------+
```

The table I'm updating to only has one record for each ID (whereas the table I'm pulling from can have multiple), and I'm trying to get the final output to look like this:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------+
| id  |               shipping_info              |
+-----+------------------------------------------|
| 123 | 6/22 - UPS abcdefgh 6/23 - USPS 12345678 |
+-----+------------------------------------------+
```

I have a query and I'm almost there:

```
update table1
set shipping_info = concat(
DATE_FORMAT(table2.date_time, '\n%c/%e - '),
table2.carrier,
table2.tracking)
where id = '123'

+-----+---------------------+
| id  |    shipping_info    |
+-----+---------------------|
| 123 | 6/22 - UPS abcdefgh |
+-----+---------------------+
```

So my problem is, when I run the update it only updates the table with the first row of data, but I need to append it with the second row as well.

Comment: Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Says invalid use of group function. I tried doing a `concat` inside of a `group_concat` and got the same error

Comment: Did you look at examples?

Comment: Yeah. I know how `group_concat` works in a Select, but would it work in my case with an Update and set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should group_concat the concatenated  string  eg:

```
select id, group_concat(concat(date,'-' , carrier,'-', tracking))
from my_table 
group by id
```

and for update

```
update my_update_table m
inner join (
   select id, group_concat(concat(date,'-' , carrier,'-', tracking)) my_col
   from my_table 
   group by id 
) t on m.id = t.id 
set m.shipping_info = t.my_col
```

Comment: How would this work in an update query? Right now, I'm doing an update and joining 4 other tables (though I left that out of my original post).

Comment: Yep, this did it. Thank you.